# clear Jpanel before next time drawing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, netbeans-8, graphics2d

I've created an analogclock were u can type a digital time and the program draws a clock that shows the time and updates it self secondly. But at every update the old lines still remain. the variables are named german but i don't think thats that much of an issue.

Code for GUI:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Uhr extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * Creates new form Uhr
     */
    public Uhr() {
        initComponents();
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        ueberschrift = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        eingabe = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        eingabe_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setName("Uhr"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
        panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        ueberschrift.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        ueberschrift.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ueberschrift.setText("Analoguhr");

        eingabe.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                eingabeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        eingabe_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        eingabe_label.setText("Uhrzeit:");

        button.setText("Uhr zeichnen");
        button.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(eingabe)
                        .addComponent(eingabe_label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 161, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 49, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(98, 98, 98)
                .addComponent(ueberschrift, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(ueberschrift, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 45, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(eingabe_label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(eingabe, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(button)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(83, 83, 83))
                    .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void uhr_paint() {
        Graphics2D leinwand = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
        leinwand.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        leinwand.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        leinwand.drawOval(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }

    public void zifferblatt() {

        Graphics2D leinwand = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
        leinwand.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        leinwand.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        double winkel;
        int zifferblatt_x, zifferblatt_y;
        int radius = 85;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            winkel = i * Math.PI / 6;
            zifferblatt_x = (int) (radius * Math.sin(winkel));
            zifferblatt_y = (int) (radius * Math.cos(winkel));
            leinwand.drawString(Integer.toString(i), 110 + zifferblatt_x, 110 - zifferblatt_y);
        }
    }

    
    
    private void eingabeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    }                                       

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        Zeit.zeit();
        uhr_paint();
        zifferblatt();
        Timer.timer();
    }                                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Uhr().setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public static javax.swing.JButton button;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField eingabe;
    private javax.swing.JLabel eingabe_label;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel label;
    public static javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ueberschrift;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Code to get the time:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author user
 * die Eingabe in Integer umwandeln
 */
public class Zeit {

    public static int stundenzeit, minutenzeit, sekundenzeit,
            stunde_x, stunde_y, minute_x, minute_y, sekunde_x, sekunde_y;
    public static String uhrzeit;

    public static void zeit() {
        try {

            uhrzeit = Uhr.eingabe.getText();
            String[] uhrzeit_split = uhrzeit.split(":");

            String stundenzeit_string = uhrzeit_split[0];
            String minutenzeit_string = uhrzeit_split[1];
            String sekundenzeit_string = uhrzeit_split[2];

            stundenzeit = Integer.parseInt(stundenzeit_string);
            minutenzeit = Integer.parseInt(minutenzeit_string);
            sekundenzeit = Integer.parseInt(sekundenzeit_string);

            if (stundenzeit < 1 | sekundenzeit > 12
                    | minutenzeit < 0 | minutenzeit > 59
                    | sekundenzeit < 0 | sekundenzeit > 59) {
                System.err.println("Bitte schreibe ein Uhrzeit!");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Bitte schreibe ein Uhrzeit!");
        }
    }
}
```

Clock hands:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import static java.awt.Color.black;
import static java.awt.Color.red;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

/**
 *
 * @author user Die Zeiger berechnen und zeichnen
 */
public class Zeiger {

    public static int Stunde_x, Stunde_y, Minute_x, Minute_y, Sekunde_x, Sekunde_y;

    public static int stundenzeit_x(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {

        Stunde_x = (int) ((int) Zeigerlänge * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((12 - Timer.stundenzeit_update) * 30) - 180 - (Timer.minutenzeit_update / 2))) + radiusUhr);
        return Stunde_x;
    }

    public static int stundenzeit_y(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {

        Stunde_y = (int) ((int) Zeigerlänge * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(((12 - Timer.stundenzeit_update) * 30) - 180 - (Timer.minutenzeit_update / 2))) + radiusUhr);
        return Stunde_y;
    }

    public static int minutenzeit_x(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {

        Minute_x = (int) (Zeigerlänge * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((60 - Timer.minutenzeit_update) * 6) - 180)) + radiusUhr);
        return Minute_x;
    }

    public static int minutenzeit_y(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {

        Minute_y = (int) (Zeigerlänge * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(((60 - Timer.minutenzeit_update) * 6) - 180)) + radiusUhr);
        return Minute_y;
    }

    public static int sekundenzeit_x(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {
        
        Sekunde_x = (int) (Zeigerlänge * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((60 - Timer.sekundenzeit_update) * 6) - 180)) + radiusUhr);
        return Sekunde_x;
    }

    public static int sekundenzeit_y(int Zeigerlänge, int radiusUhr) {
        Sekunde_y = (int) (Zeigerlänge * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(((60 - Timer.sekundenzeit_update) * 6) - 180)) + radiusUhr);
        return Sekunde_y;
    }

    public static void stundenzeiger_paint() {
        Graphics2D leinwand = (Graphics2D) Uhr.panel.getGraphics();
        int radiusUhr = 110;
        stundenzeit_x(40, radiusUhr);
        stundenzeit_y(40, radiusUhr);
        leinwand.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) 1.5));
        leinwand.setColor(black);
        leinwand.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        leinwand.drawLine(110, 110, Stunde_x, Stunde_y);
    }

    public static void minutenzeiger_paint() {
        Graphics2D leinwand = (Graphics2D) Uhr.panel.getGraphics();
        int radiusUhr = 110;
        minutenzeit_x(70, radiusUhr);
        minutenzeit_y(70, radiusUhr);
        leinwand.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) 1.25));
        leinwand.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        leinwand.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        leinwand.drawLine(110, 110, Minute_x, Minute_y);
    }

    public static synchronized void sekundenzeiger_paint() {
        Graphics2D leinwand = (Graphics2D) Uhr.panel.getGraphics();
        int radiusUhr = 110;
        sekundenzeit_x(80, radiusUhr);
        sekundenzeit_y(80, radiusUhr);
        leinwand.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        leinwand.setColor(red);
        leinwand.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        leinwand.drawLine(110, 110, Sekunde_x, Sekunde_y);
    }
}
```

And finally the timer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 *
 * @author user 
 * Sekuendliches aktualisieren des Timer-labels und der Uhr
 */
public class Timer {

    static int sekundenzeit_update = Zeit.sekundenzeit,
            minutenzeit_update = Zeit.minutenzeit,
            stundenzeit_update = Zeit.stundenzeit;

    static String uhrzeit_update = Zeit.stundenzeit + ":"
            + Zeit.minutenzeit + ":" + Zeit.sekundenzeit;

    public static void timer() {
        Runnable helloRunnable;
        helloRunnable = () -> {

            Uhr.label.setText("");
            Uhr.label.setText(uhrzeit_update);
            timer_ausführen();
            Zeiger.stundenzeiger_paint();
            Zeiger.minutenzeiger_paint();
            Zeiger.sekundenzeiger_paint();

        };
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void timer_ausführen() {

        sekundenzeit_update += 1;

        if (sekundenzeit_update > 60) {
            sekundenzeit_update = 0;
            minutenzeit_update += 1;

            if (minutenzeit_update > 60) {
                minutenzeit_update = 0;
                stundenzeit_update += 1;
            }
        }
        uhrzeit_update = stundenzeit_update + ":" + minutenzeit_update
                + ":" + sekundenzeit_update;

    }
}
```

clock in the beginning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf5Hu.png

[clock after one minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjOrs.png)

I did this with Netbeans and I had the idea to draw this by hand but I really dont know how to do this.

Comment: If you draw on a drawing `JPanel`, the call to `super.paintComponent` will clear the drawing area.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way Swing JComponents are supposed to be used. You are supposed to create a subclass (of JPanel in your case) and in the subclass override `paintComponent`, which should be made to always paint the correct time whenever it is called. Then you can use a javax.swing.Timer to call `repaint` every second.

Sie sollen Swing in ein anderes weg nutzen. Sie mussen JPanel "Subclassen", und dann diese funktion "paintComponent" uberritten :)

Comment: I already thought of this but when I tried it out, I didnt know where to set the location of the panel bc it is in the lower left corner of the frame. the frame 440 time 300 big and my panel is 220 times 220 big. then the panel should have the location 80, 220 right?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/learn/index.html